# The type com.google.gwt.cell.client.EditTextCell.ViewData is not visible

Tags: java, gwt

I got following problem: I have a CellTable, which I want to contain an EditTextCell to edit the displayed data of my table's row. In order to do this my EditTextCell needs a ViewData object, which I am not able to initialize, since I get following error: *The type com.google.gwt.cell.client.EditTextCell.ViewData is not visible*

```
EditTextCell editTextCell = new EditTextCell();
String key = "foo";
com.google.gwt.cell.client.EditTextCell.ViewData viewData;
editTextCell.setViewData(key, viewData);
```

Does anyone know this issue and how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to access `ViewData`? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: The ViewData is, what contains the textbox's visible text, isn't it? So I propably need one, if I want to display something in it first before editing(?).

Comment: You mean when your actual value is empty? something like a _placeholder_?

Comment: I rather thought about displaying the actual data in the textbox itself, but making it not editable until I click on an editbutton besides it.

Comment: Then you don't need to deal with `ViewData`, just return the actual data from your `Column`s `getValue` and it'll display in the cell. For the edit button, you probably want a custom cell though (duplicating most of the functionality of `EditTextCell`).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably private so you don't modify the internal structure. I believe you have to think of this problem the other way around, add your editor to the view and let it pass the data internally, instead of trying to extract the data yourself and pass it to the editor.